# Zip a directory and save it in another destination

Tags: python-3.x, zip

I have the following script for zip a directory:

```
zipobj = zipfile.ZipFile(zip_file_name + '.zip', 'w', zipfile.ZIP_DEFLATED)

rootlen = len(target_dir) + 1
for base, dirs, files in os.walk(target_dir):
    for file in files:
        fn = os.path.join(base, file)
        zipobj.write(fn, fn[rootlen:])
```

Currently it works fine, but the new zip file is saved in my root path.

How do I save it in other destination?

Comment: Provide a full path to where you want to put it, rather than just a filename?

Comment: It worked :) Thanks!